# Storing Network Packets in Tabular Form

Tags: computer-networks

For network packets coming over TCP/IP protocol, have you ever confronted a situation where you need to store those network packets in tabular form similar to how tabular tables in databases? For example, keep the dst IP, dst src, TCP/UDP, payload, etc.?

If you ever find yourself in a situation where you need to store network packets over TCP/IP in tabular form, can you please explain the motivation for that from you own experience?

Comment: (I haven't been there myself, but see its value in troubleshooting telecommunications equipment like switches (en.wikipedia: [network](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) *and* [packet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching)?!).)

Comment: @greybeard. Thank you. Are you referring to routing tables?

Comment: Whatever needs checking. Come to think of it, I have seen such hardware operated: in the days before twisted pair, when a broken or disconnected cable or terminator created havoc for the whole segment, as did using 75 Ohms or even 93 or not connecting the T-connector directly to the NIC, but creating a considerable length of "stub" using another cable between both. Ah, and a firmware/software version in later years - may well have been layers above the physical one.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here.